# Order not found for some shopware GET order requests

Tags: shopware

I am using magnalister on my shopware store to import my amazon orders. Unfortunately,
when I use shopware's API calls (GET order details) to fetch some orders I get:
{"success":false,"message":"Order by id xxxxx not found"} while these are all valid,
not cancelled orders imported from amazon. Also noticed that shopware shows order
status as -1 or 4 for this, which is used for cancelled orders. Can you please help me
understand why and how I could get these? Could magnalister be using those order statuses in some cases when they are fully completed orders? Thanks in
advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using as xxxxx the internal Shopware id or did you use the ordernumber?
According to the offical docs (https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/api-resource-orders/#get)  you have to add the parameter **?useNumberAsId=true**.

These are the default order states:

[image: list of default order states]

To Filter for a specific state you have to add the following parameter: **filter[orderStatusId]={id of the state}** on the order listing Request